# How to source a variable list pulled using sqlplus in bash without creating a file

Tags: bash, variables

Im trying to source a variable list which is populated into one single variable in bash.

I then want to source this single variable to the contents (which are other variables) of the variable are available to the script.

I want to achieve this without having to spool the sqlplus file then source this file (this already works as I tried it).

Please find below what Im trying:

```
#!/bin/bash

var_list=$(sqlplus -S /@mydatabase << EOF
set pagesize 0
set trimspool on
set headsep off
set echo off
set feedback off
set linesize 1000
set verify off
set termout off
select varlist from table;
EOF
)

#This already works when I echo any variable from the list
#echo "$var_list" > var_list.dat
#. var_list.dat
#echo "$var1, $var2, $var3"

#Im trying to achieve the following
. $(echo "var_list")
echo "$any_variable_from_var_list"
```

The contents of var_list from the database are as follows:

```
var1="Test1"
var2="Test2"
var3="Test3"
```

I also tried sourcing it other ways such as:

```
. <<< $(echo "$var_list")
. $(cat "$var_list")
```

Im not sure if I need to read in each line now using a while loop.

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can:

```
. /dev/stdin <<<"$varlist"
```

`<<<` is a here string. It redirects the content of data behind `<<<` to standard input.

`/dev/stdin` represents standard input. So reading from the 0 file descriptor is like opening `/dev/stdin` and calling `read()` on resulting file descriptor.

Because `source` command needs a filename, we pass to is `/dev/stdin` and redirect the data to be read to standard input. That way `source` reads the commands from standard input thinking it's reading from file, while we pass our data to the input that we want to pass.

Using `/dev/stdin` for tools that expect a file is quite common. I have no idea what references to give, I'll link: [bash manual here strings](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Strings), [Posix 7 base definitions 2.1.1p4 last bullet point](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap02.html), [linux kernel documentation on /dev/ directory entires](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/admin-guide/devices.rst), [bash manual shell builtins](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins), maybe [C99 7.19.3p7](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#7.19.3p7).

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Please explain why this would work too, maybe with a reference to where I can read more about this please?

Comment: This partially works. Unfortuantely it doesnt work on cases where the var1 for example is multiline:

var1="Test1
Test2"

Any ideas?

Comment: [It works for me, repl link](https://repl.it/@kamilcukrowski/FabulousEssentialTechnicians)

Comment: OK it works now, I didnt realise I was still using stdin <<< $(echo "$varlist". Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I needed a way to store dotenv values in files locally and vars for DevOps pipelines, so I could then source to the runtime environment on demand (from file when available and vars when not). More though, I needed to store different dotenv sets in different vars and use them based on the source branch (which I load to $ENV in .gitlab-ci.yml via `export ENV=${CI_COMMIT_BRANCH:=develop}`). With this I'll have developEnv, qaEnv, and productionEnv, each being a var containing it's appropriate dotenv contents (being redundant to be clear.)

```sh
unset FOO; # Clear so we can confirm loading after
ENV=develop; # 

developEnv="VERSION=1.2.3
FOO=bar"; # Creating a simple dotenv in a var, with linebreak (as the files passed through will have)

envVarName=${ENV}Env # Our dynamic var-name
source <(cat <<< "${!envVarName}") # Using the dynamic name, 
echo $FOO;
# bar
```